# ASP.NET 4.0 WebForms Routing Javascript not works

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, url-routing

I'm try to use ASP.NET 4.0 WebForms Routing. Here is my RegisterRoutes function:

```
 void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}"); 
        routes.MapPageRoute("GoodInfo", "catalog/good/{good}", "~/GoodInfo.aspx");
        routes.MapPageRoute("GoodGroup", "catalog/group/{group}", "~/default.aspx");
    }
```

For pages like `/catalog/group/{group}` everything is ok. But there are problems with pages `catalog/good/{good}`.

First strange thing: when I open this page it calls twice. So I see what value comes for `Page.RouteData.Values["good"]`. First time in `Page.RouteData.Values["good"]` has the right value (my goodId) but the second time I got the string value "WebResource.axd"!

So my highslide JavaScript does not work on the page. And when I click on highslide image the page reloads instead of executing the JavaScript.

I added this line `routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");` but it didn't helped me. Any ideas?

Comment: I got a similar problem in on of my apps and to "fix" it, I added changed the reference links to all resources (images, css and js) on our pages, so instead of `<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/something.js"></script>` I've written something like this `<script type="text/javascript" src="/../scripts/something.js"></script>`. Note the extra slash on the script source. VS will complain about this, but I will work fine in runtime. I took me a while to figure this out and I had to try different combinations of paths until I finally got this path like this. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem! The solution consists of 2 parts.
Firstly I changed my scripts definition from

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/something.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/../scripts/something.js"></script>
```

Thanks [MilkyWayJoe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54364/milkywayjoe) fot that solution.

Secondly I added Ignore Routing

```
routes.Ignore("catalog/good/{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

instead of:

```
routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

So my web resources have no more routes on pages  like `http://mysite.com/catalog/good/41`

Also I have script events on the page like `http://mysite.com/catalog/good/41/event/seq/1`. To catch all parameters I add to my route rules this

```
   routes.Ignore("catalog/good/{good}/{*query1}");
   routes.Ignore("catalog/good/{good}/{query1}/{*query2}");
   routes.Ignore("catalog/good/{good}/{query1}/{query2}/{*query3}");
   routes.Ignore("catalog/good/{good}/{query1}/{query2}/{query3}/{*query4}");
```

And don't forget that your `Ignore` declarations must be placed before `MapPageRoute` declarations:

```
routes.Ignore("catalog/good/{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.MapPageRoute("GoodInfo", "catalog/good/{good}", "~/GoodInfo.aspx");`enter code here`
```