# ASP.NET WebForms Routing Javascript Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms, url-routing

I have some problems with JavaScript using ASP.NET 4.0 WebForms Routing.

My code:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");             
    routes.MapPageRoute("GoodInfo", "catalog/good/{good}", "~/GoodInfo.aspx");
    routes.MapPageRoute("GoodGroup", "catalog/group/{group}", "~/default.aspx");
}
```

With no routing everything is ok. But when I use it I got an error on hte page (in Firebug)

> Error: jQuery is not defined

on this line:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    HideBlocks();
});
```

So my JavaScript does not work on the page that was routed.

I added this line `routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");` but it didn't helped me.

Comment: I posted solution here: [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503746/asp-net-4-0-webforms-routing-javascript-not-works)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved my problem! The solution consists of 2 parts.
Firstly I changed my scripts definition from

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/something.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/../scripts/something.js"></script>
```

Thanks [MilkyWayJoe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54364/milkywayjoe) fot that solution.

Secondly I added Ignore Routing

```
routes.Ignore("catalog/good/{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

instead of:

```
routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

So my web resources have no more routes on pages  like `http://mysite.com/catalog/good/41`

Also I have script events on the page like `http://mysite.com/catalog/good/41/event/seq/1`. To catch all parameters I add to my route rules this

```
   routes.Ignore("catalog/good/{good}/{*query1}");
   routes.Ignore("catalog/good/{good}/{query1}/{*query2}");
   routes.Ignore("catalog/good/{good}/{query1}/{query2}/{*query3}");
   routes.Ignore("catalog/good/{good}/{query1}/{query2}/{query3}/{*query4}");
```

And don't forget that your `Ignore` declarations must be placed before `MapPageRoute` declarations:

```
routes.Ignore("catalog/good/{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.MapPageRoute("GoodInfo", "catalog/good/{good}", "~/GoodInfo.aspx");`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the generated source of your page, is the jQuery library included?

If you are including jQuery via a resource, double check that it is included and that it is before that line that errors.

Comment: Yes, jQuery included before this line. All works fine if I call page directly without routing.